# How to get property Data from annotation?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mapkit

[image]
How to get property Data from annotation? 
I have:

```
listSelected = [Properties]()
```

I have problem to get image from list property to set it in pin
and have another problem to get my list to use in alertcontrollr to show my the property.

So how to do it?

```
func drowPropertyOnMap(list: [Properties]) {
    self.spinner.isHidden = false
    self.spinner.startAnimating()

    var annotations = [MKPointAnnotation]()

    for (index, property) in list.enumerated() {

        let propertyLat: CLLocationDegrees = property.Latitude as! CLLocationDegrees
        let propertyLong: CLLocationDegrees = property.Longitude as! CLLocationDegrees

        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: propertyLat, longitude: propertyLong)

        let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1)
        let center: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude)

        let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span)

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        pointAnnotation.coordinate = coordinate
        pointAnnotation.title = property.Title
        pointAnnotation.subtitle = property.Description

        annotations.append(pointAnnotation)
    }

    // stop spinner
    self.spinner.stopAnimating()
    self.spinner.isHidden = true

    self.mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
}

//  MARK: - MapViewDelegate

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
        //if annotation is not an MKPointAnnotation (eg. MKUserLocation),
        //return nil so map draws default view for it (eg. blue dot)...
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "test"

    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)

    if annotationView == nil {

        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        annotationView?.image = UIImage(named:"homeIconPin")
        annotationView?.isEnabled = true
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true

        let leftIconView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 53, height: 53))
        leftIconView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_3")
        annotationView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftIconView

        let btn = UIButton(type: .infoLight)
        annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
        return annotationView
    } else {
        //we are re-using a view, update its annotation reference...
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    return annotationView
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {



    let property = view.annotation as! Properties
    let placeName = property.Title! as String
    let placeInfo = property.Description! as String


    let ac = UIAlertController(title: placeName, message: placeInfo, preferredStyle: .alert)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
    present(ac, animated: true)


}
```

So I need to call property in:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
}
```

How to make that?

Comment: the problem it was in I have a list of property and I wanna use some property with all data in this property

Comment: Your annotation isn't a `Properties`, it's an `MKPointAnnotation`.  Rather than wrap your property in an `MKPointAnnotation` you could make your `Properties` class conform to the `MKAnnotation` protocol and add them to your map directly.

Comment: how to do it? Can you explain what can i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was solve the problem so we need to add new **Class** from **MKPointAnnotation**

to get index path from annotation

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class Annotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var index = 0
}
```

after that we will go to our controller and add our code

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var listSelected = [Properties]()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)       
    drowPropertyOnMap(list: listSelected)
}

//  MARK: - drowPropertyOnMap

func drowPropertyOnMap(list: [Properties]) {

    self.spinner.isHidden = false
    self.spinner.startAnimating()

    var annotations = [MKPointAnnotation]()

    for (index, property) in list.enumerated() {

        let propertyLat: CLLocationDegrees = property.Latitude as! CLLocationDegrees
        let propertyLong: CLLocationDegrees = property.Longitude as! CLLocationDegrees

        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: propertyLat, longitude: propertyLong)

        let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.5, 0.5)
        let center: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude)

        let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span)

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let pointAnnotation = Annotation()
        pointAnnotation.index = index
        pointAnnotation.coordinate = coordinate
        pointAnnotation.title = property.Title
        pointAnnotation.subtitle = property.Description


        annotations.append(pointAnnotation)
    }

    // stop spinner
    self.spinner.stopAnimating()
    self.spinner.isHidden = true

    self.mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
}

//  MARK: - MapViewDelegate

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if !(annotation is Annotation)
    {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "test"

    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)

    if annotationView == nil {

        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        annotationView?.image = UIImage(named:"homeIconPin")
        annotationView?.isEnabled = true
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true

        if let myAnnotation = annotation as? Annotation {

            let selectedProp = listSelected[myAnnotation.index]

            let imageString = selectedProp.Image

            let leftIconView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 53, height: 53))
            leftIconView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageString ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholderProperty.png"))

            annotationView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftIconView
        }

        let btn = UIButton(type: .infoLight)
        annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
        return annotationView

    } else {
        //we are re-using a view, update its annotation reference...
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    return annotationView
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    homeView.isHidden = false

    if let myAnnotation = view.annotation as? Annotation {

        let selectedProp = listSelected[myAnnotation.index]

        self.selectedTableData = selectedProp

        self.homeTitleLabel.text = selectedProp.Title
        self.homeSubtitleLabel.text = selectedProp.Description

        let imageString = selectedProp.Image

        self.homeImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageString ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholderProperty.png"))
    }
}
}
```